# AndroidAppLinks - Firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: API: AppDataSearch.LIGHTWEIGHT_API is not available on this device

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implemented Android app links in my xamarin forms apps as below

```
 _applink = new AppLinkEntry
                        {
                            AppLinkUri = new Uri(string.Format(App.AppLinkUrl,  id.ToString())),
                            Description = name,
                            Title = name,
                            IsLinkActive = true,
                            Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromFile("icon.png")
                        };

                        Application.Current.AppLinks?.RegisterLink(_applink);
```

In general it works fine but I have a phone with custom Rom (CarbonRom) installed and it throw exception below on the line `RegisterLink` method.
I have google play store and play services installed and i am logged in with my gmail. 
why is it throwing this exception? what is it depends on?
And i don't see any possibility to pre-check if it is available to prevent this. even wrapping try catch around is not able to handle this exception.

```
AndroidAppLinks+AndroidActionFailureListener.OnFailure (Java.Lang.Exception e)
IOnFailureListenerInvoker.n_OnFailure_Ljava_lang_Exception_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.113(intptr,intptr,intptr)
com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: API: AppDataSearch.LIGHTWEIGHT_API is not available on this device.
com.google.firebase.zzb.zzs(Unknown Source:24)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zze.zzr(Unknown Source:4)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzv(Unknown Source:27)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source:203)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source:2)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzj(Unknown Source:14)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source:43)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzajo(Unknown Source:54)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source:275)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: I got the same issue.

The exception is throwing in this class (AndroidActionFailureListener)
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppLinks/AndroidAppLinks.cs

I don't find out how we can catch the exception to prevent the crash.

Comment: Added the issue in XF github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6622

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear your data and Cache by Settings > Apps > Google Play services > Storage > Manage Space > Clear All Data, and try it again if it works.

Comment: nope. this doesnt work and i believe it has nothing to do with the other issues regarding firebase_auth_api